# Snowflake snowsql get command with pattern for multiple files download on windows environment returning error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to download multiple files from a named snowflake stage to my local machine using snowsql cli with the pattern parameter option but getting the error for the pattern option itself. the same option works with list command from cli. Below is the command which works perfectly.

```
list @DEMO_USER_STAGE pattern='.*data_0_0_1.*';
```

above command list all the pattern matching files. But when i run below command i get error.

```
get @DEMO_USER_STAGE pattern='.*data_0_0_1.*' file://C:\Users\Lycanworld\Desktop\Snowflake\data_unload\ ;
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 21 unexpected 'pattern'.
syntax error line 1 at position 46 unexpected 'file://C:\Users\Lycanworld\Desktop\Snowflake\data_unload\'.
```

on trying the above command for single file instead of "pattern" it runs successfully to download file to local machine. Can anyone advice the problem in above command ?

Comment: I believe `pattern` needs to be the last parameter.

Comment: I confirmed Mike's assertion, and while doing so it dawned on my why this is the case. Although the pattern is a named parameter, the files parameter is not. It only appears to be named because it starts with `files:` but named parameters start with `param_name = ` so the files parameter is a positional parameter.

Comment: tried pattern parameter at the end but got below error. get @DEMO_USER_STAGE file://C:\Users\Lycanworld\Desktop\Snowflake\data_unload pattern='.*data_0_0_11.*' ;

| file               | size | status | message                                                                                           |
|--------------------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| data_0_0_11.csv.gz |   -1 | ERROR  | An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden, file=data_0_0_11.csv.gz |

Comment: @MikeWalton can you please help with above mentioned error ?

Answer (score 0):

According to official doc:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get.html#syntax

The SYNTAX is:

```
GET internalStage file://<path_to_file>/<filename>
    [ PARALLEL = <integer> ]
    [ PATTERN = '<regex_pattern>'' ]
```

So you need to swap file location with PATTERN.